# Reasoning Behind PHP5 Protected Variables

Tags: php, protected

Can you explain what the reasoning would be on why I would want to use "protected" versus "public" or "private" on some class variables and methods in PHP5? I've just yet to find a case where I thought I needed "protected", and have either opted for "public" or "private" based on the intent. Even when working in teams, I have still yet to find a case (based on my knowledge thus far) of why "protected" is necessary for class variables and methods.

Comment: I really like your question and wish there was some way you could ping me when you create new ones like this. You know... meta programming questions specific to PHP 5.  One way I know you can "ping" me is by leaving a comment here (it'll show up in my inbox). I'd love to help you out and this helps me analyze why I do things which helps me become a better coder, too.

Comment: I added a bounty so this would "stand out" as an important question for people to ponder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance, the [Flourish library](http://flourishlib.com/)'s fDate class provides a lot of functionality but not everything I need.  So I extended w/ my own class.

I soon found out that its core internal variable, fDate::$date (time in seconds since 1970), was a *private* property.  This made it **impossible** for me to access it in my subclass ThriveDate.  Once the maintainer of Flourish changed it to a `protected` property, I was able to use it and thus adequately extend fDate.

Since you never know who might need to extend your class, and by how much, in the future, it's always best to make every internal property protected, **unless there are great reasons for the property to never be modified by subclasses**.

TL;DR: Private properties should be as rare as public properties: e.g. used almost never.

Comment: Thanks. That's the compelling reason I needed to hear! :)

Comment: Say, you make mention that I should "almost never" use public properties. Can you explain a little more? I use public properties on my classes sometimes when it's tiring to do sets and gets and I have like a User object and I want to set name, age, etc. However, ah, maybe it's all about trusting the data, which is why you might prefer the set/get technique. Right?

Comment: I would love to. Encapsulation: In a single sentence: Encapsulation means "Don't Ask; Tell!"  If you **ever** have to query an object's state to determine whether to do something with that object, your object is very poorly encapsulated.  A well-encapsulated class will usually have 0 public properties, 0 setters and maybe 1 or 2 getters per 5 non-public properties. For more info you have to contact me.

Comment: I disagree.  For a very long time, I habitually made non-public members protected, on the basis of "well, maybe I'll need it some day."  For me, the clinching reason for changing this and using private members whenever possible is this: a protected member is exposed, part of your object's contact.  If you *ever* change how it works, you could sink downstream code.  Thus, it's more maintainable to use private members.  Use protected only if you have a real need to do so.

Comment: -1 I'm not much of a downvoter, but protected variables can be just as dangerous as public. You should be making your variables private unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: I also feel "unless there are great reasons for the property to never be modified by subclasses" is a poor decision. Classes should be **open to extension, closed to modification**

Comment: @glowcoder I don't understand your reasoning. What do you do in the situation @Theodore describes - when you publish a class someone else might want to extend in the future? Making the variable private means you effectively make it impossible to access it from an extended class. Why is `protected` not the way to go here?

Comment: @all, people tend to *drastically* over-use the inheritance model, as opposed to composition and the Decorator/Strategy patterns. As long as you only inherit when appropriately, this greatly mitigates the need to change code later.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Can you recommend a book to me on design patterns, but geared for PHP? I'm trying to find one that explains the reasoning why certain patterns are used, and which uses PHP examples only.

Comment: -1: I'd say it's the exact opposite: it's always best to make every internal property `private` unless there is a pressing need to make it  `protected`. It's best to favor immutability. Leaving properties as `protected` willy-nilly makes it harder for you to enforce a consistent contract between all subclasses. Furthermore, once you expose something, you make refactoring harder because any attempt to modify behavior or even remove behavior could be a breaking change. Leave something open to being extended if the extension cannot violate the contract. On another note, composition is preferable.

Comment: Also, please don't ask people to "contact you for further information" or "buy your book". That's borderline spammy.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Private makes sense when one overly relies on the Inheritance paradigm. Fortunately, that paradigm is going of style like crazy. Secondly, it's not our responsibility to worry about how people use our code. If one is *so* worried about a future class screwing up protected values, why not mark every class as "final" and be done with it?

Comment: @VivinPaliath As far as refactoring goes, I totally agree that with an app that overly relies on inheritance, changing protected variables names, in fact, make it harder to refactor. In that case, just create an Adapter design pattern to keep the old interface, and voila! My personal repository has **277 classes**, of those **43 extend from another class**. That's just 18%, so refactoring isn't *that* bad compared to the gains of not having ot change interfaces when the need to extend arises.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Disagree once again. You should **always** worry about how people are using your class because that forces you to think about proper encapsulation and possible abstraction-leakage. There's a better solution than making the class `final` (which is acceptable in some cases): it's to make properties `private`. Making everything `protected` is a form of abstraction leakage as well. Your anecdotal evidence aside, creating adapters in this scenario is just a band-aid over a bad architecture. Why not design it right the first time? Agree with you about composition vs. inheritance.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Most of the time, the vast majority, one cannot "design it right the first time", as they don't start the code, and trying to do so just wastes cycles on "intellectual purity" which do not produce results and add to overhead. Instead, focus on creating friendly APIs and not worrying if the end-dev is stupid enough to shoot themselves in the foot. That's self-righteous, btw. Trust them not to.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Designing it right first is a no-brainer. There is no self-righteousness here. It's just good software-engineering and good design. It's a question of working with something that is well-designed beforehand vs. working with something that is poorly designed and has a bunch of patchwork and duct-tape design. No design is perfect, but one can strive to achieve it. All good software engineers spend time beforehand coming up with good design. There is no "intellectual purity" here; just good software engineering. Amateurs/novices usually jump into coding without any forethought.

Answer (score 1):

With `protected` its possible for an object of the class or any subclass to access that property. So its useful, if you want this restriction.

This is not strictly necessary, you can also make every property `public`, but then you will lose every control, who access and/or changes it. Also others may get confused, what all these "public properties" are good for, for which they have access to.

On the other hand you can make every property `private`, but then also every subclass can not access it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What about a real life example:

```
<?
// burguers.php

/* abstract */ class BurguerClass {
  // nobody knows about these secret function
  private function addSecretRecipeSauce() { ... }  

  // these one can can change in subclasses
  // cannot be called globally
  protected /* virtual */ function addBread() { ... }  
  protected /* virtual */ function addSalad() { ... }  
  protected /* virtual */ function addMeat() { ... }
  protected /* virtual */ function addExtraIngredients() { ... }

  // these one it can be access globally
  public /* virtual */ function makeBurguer() {
    $this->addBread();
    $this->addSalad();
    $this->addMeat();
    $this->addExtraIngredients();
    $this->addSecretRecipeSauce();
  }  
}

/* concrete */ class CheeseBurguerClass extends BurguerClass {
  protected /* virtual */ function addCheese() { ... }

  public /* override */ function makeBurguer() {
    $this->addBread();
    $this->addSalad();
    $this->addMeat();
    $this->addExtraIngredients();
    // we add this one:
    $this->addCheese();
  } 
}

/* concrete */ class RanchStyleBurguerClass extends BurguerClass {
  protected /* override */ function addExtraIngredients() { ... }
}

/* concrete */ class EastCoastVegetarianStyleBurguerClass extends BurguerClass {
  protected /* override */ function addMeat() {
    // use soy "meat"
  }
  protected /* override */ function addExtraIngredients() { ... }
}

function burguers_main() {
    $Cheesburguer = new CheeseBurguerClass();

    // can be access
    $Cheesburguer->makeBurguer();
}

// execute it
burguers_main();

?>
```

You just open the "Can I have a Cheesburguer" Software Development company. You are the C.E.O., you have several subordinates. You teach subordinates they can make new products based on the "burguerClass" recipe, and make new recipes.

You tell your employees how to "addBread" , "addSalad", "addMeat", "addExtraIngredients", and that operations can be changed by new ones, but cannot sell them separately, only can used in the "makeBurguer" operation.

But, you dont teach your employees the "addSecretRecipe" operation.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that Private methods and properties cannot be seen by classes that extend; whereas Protected methods and properties can be seen but used only by the class it is defined within.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 0):

when designing classes, isn't it normal to have private and public
variables or properties.

Granted my OOP experience is very limited, having
access to OOP development in CA-Visual Objects, Clipper, VB, and ASP.

But it was normal to have a series of public properties one could access
directly and then properties that could only be access by the class itself.

Of course in VB and ASP these were defined with Get, Let and Set methods,
but you could still access them directly.

You could also design properties that were read only as well.
Perhaps this is because of operator overloading...

Comment: You should get the book, Refactoring. It's a hard book to read, and somewhat boring, but it explains some of what I think I read from Theodore R. Smith here in this post. This should explain your question which you posted under answers.

Answer (score 0):

I use protected methods and attributes rather than private mainly for **testing** purposes. This way it's much easier to create class mocks when writing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

OOP doesn't ends at organizing your code to classes (as structured programming doesn't ends at splitting code to functions). PHP is a script language, so when using it as OOP language, we should set up contstraints for ourselves.

I was very lucky, when I first met OOP, the language was Java, and the book was Bruce Ekcel - Thinking in Java (you can purchase it on Amazon or other stores, also previous editions can be downloaded from here for free: http://www.mindviewinc.com/Books/downloads.html ). I can recommend that book, even for PHP programmers. If you're not complete beginner, you will understand everything, and adopt it to PHP. I'm trying to programming in PHP like if it were Java (at least, the OOP part; there're no such cool associative arrays in Java, as in PHP).

Also, private, protected, and public categories are not too precise. Public should be split to "API method" and "can be called from other classes" (see "friendly"), protected should distinguish between "should be overwritten" and "must be implemented".

Learn OOP, it's worth.

There's one more thing I wanna to say, a basic pattern of OOP: use getters/setters, don't use public properties, if you use public properties, you just graved it to rock. Say, there's a status flag, now it has 2 possible state values, but if you wanna extend it, all the code must be revised, which use it. Use setState() and getState(), which functions first are simple (*$this->state = $param;* and *return $this->state*), but there will be no problem with extending the meaning of state, then you should re-write only these methods, even in the case, if the state is a derived value (e.g. its value is calculated from more flags).

There're several less or more deep similar topics in OOP, this getter/setter is probably the most important of the basic ones.

So, my tips are:

- use OOP, it's your friend;
- use PHP as like it were JAVA (a strict OOP language), and not like in FORTRAN.